# Migrating from WebPack to Angular-CLI 6

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli-v6

I need to migrate a ***Angular 6*** project that has a **WebPack** configured on it to **Angular-CLI 6**, I have some concern about broke something, so I need some guidance to acquire a good code and accomplish this goal.

Follow some samples of my ***big*** WebPack file:

**Some Plugins**:

```js
//Plugins Nest - OPTIONS
var extractSassPlugin = new ExtractTextPlugin({
  filename: 'css/app.global.css', // This is not just t
  allChunks: true
});

var extractCssPlugin = new ExtractTextPlugin({
  filename: 'css/app.modules.css', // This is not just t
  allChunks: true
});

var htmlPlugin = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: 'src/index.html'
});

var cleanPlugin = new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']);

var optionsPlugin = new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
  debug: DEV_ENV || LOCAL_ENV || KARMA
});

var uglifyJs;

if (PROD_ENV === true) {
  uglifyJs = new UglifyJsPlugin({
    //.. Just if, the code is minified
    uglifyOptions: {
      compress: true,
      comments: false
    }
  });
} else {
  uglifyJs = new UglifyJsPlugin({
    //.. Just if, the code is minified
  });
}
```

I have some **CopyWebpackPlugin**:

```js
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      { from: 'src/somewhere', to: 'js/libs/somewhere-else' },
```

Some specifics `.css` extensions to be compiled:

```js
{
        test: /\.print\.scss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].min.css',
              outputPath: 'css/print/',
              publicPath: '../'
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              outputStyle: 'compressed'
            }
          }
        ]
      }
```

And `entry` and `output` using split .js (hash-chunk) to let the code to be more easy to be load to the browser:

```js
entry: {
    polyfills: './src/polyfills.browser.ts',
    vendor: './src/vendor.browser.ts',
    main: outputMain
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name]-[hash].js',
    chunkFilename: '[name]-[hash]-chunk.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
```

Any help is valid, thanks!

Comment: If you have a specific problem with the migration, please provide a [mcve]. Otherwise this question is too broad for SO.

Comment: Thanks to the tip, more details about my question is already on it.